Is Philip Schaff an important voice in patristic studies?
Philip Schaff's anthologies of the Church Fathers are frequently referenced in online conversation due to their accessibility on newadvent and elsewhere, but my question is about Schaff as a patristic commentator. I am not aware of any impact he has had on the later study of the Fathers. Are his commentaries on the Fathers of any scholarly influence or value?
God bless,
Daniel

Can you be more specific on which works you're referring by "commentaries on the Fathers"?   Are you referring to his introductions within the 38 volume Early Church Fathers translation, such as this one for St. Augustine?  Also, it doesn't appear that he edited each of the 38 volumes (example: Volume 3 is edited by Allan Menzies).  Maybe he's more of a series editor?

Yes, that is mainly what I'm referring to. My question is really about what scholarly weight should be accorded his comments in his collections of the Fathers, and whether he historically exerted any influence on the field of patristic study apart from making these texts more available in translation?

Thank you for that clarification; this will help potential answerer, so you may want to integrate your comment into the post.  As of now, the Q is borderline opinion-based.  One way to make it more objective is to ask for references showing the scholarly weight of his introductions, for example by showing how those are cited in scholarly books / journal articles.
